# Visual Studio Code: code not running for C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

When I try to run this code and press the play button on the top right:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void test()
{

int v[]={0,1,2,3};

for(auto x:v)
    cout << x << '\n';
}

int main()
{

}
```

I get two warnings:

[image]

1p7.cpp:10:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
for(auto x:v)
    ^
1p7.cpp:10:11: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
for(auto x:v)
          ^
2 warnings generated.

When I run the code via terminal I get:

```
1p7.cpp:10:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
for(auto x:v)
    ^
1p7.cpp:10:11: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
for(auto x:v)
          ^
2 warnings generated.
```

The same thing. I used g++ for terminal but I believe clang is used for VS code.

I already changed the setting to:

[image]

and I ran brew update and brew upgrade on the terminal. g++ -version gives:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

tasks.json is:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": [
                // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/t:build",
                // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated. This is really frustrating. I can use the std=c++11 in the terminal to make the code run but I would rather have this 1) automatically run without adding that every time I have a new program 2) would like it to work in VS code.

Comment: what is the problem? Those are warnings. Warnings should be taken serious, but it is up to you if the warning really points to an error, if not there is no problem

Comment: perhaps you want to call the `test()` function in `main` to see some output ....

Comment: you need to explicitly state the c++ version i think

Comment: Was the C++ standard you set for the entire VS Code? Could your project override that and not use C++11?

Comment: Yea but why would it continue to have warnings when I already switched VS code to c++11?

Comment: I think VS Code sets it automatically to c++98 but I changed it to c++11 as shown in the pic above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Build

clang will need the `-std=c++11` option. [Clang c++11](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

g++ will accept `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` [Gnu C++ standards support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11)

### Executing test()

You will need to call function test within main for the test to execute.

```
int main()
{
  test();
}
```

#### Note:

I use cmake with a CMakeLists.txt to build my projects.

Comment: Can you expound on how you use cmake to build your projects?